# How to data-model dynamic open/close times for booking a room

Tags: datamodel

this is my first post. I have been searching for the best way to do this but have not had much success so I decided to post here.

I have a database model that is going to be used to book rooms in a complex. These rooms need to have open and close times to determine when they can be booked. For example, one room may be open from 8am to 10pm but another might be open from 10am to 5pm etc.

One of the requirements, and the part I'm stuck on, is that the open/close times for rooms needs to changed based on a time period similar to a "season" but this time period is manually set by an admin unlike a season.

So, from Jan-11 to March-28, a specific room may to open from 10am to 5pm but from March-29 to July-17 it may be open from 8am to 7pm.

I'm guessing that I need another table or two to store the "time periods" as well as the open/close time of the room during those periods.

Can anyone point me in the right direction or show me an example?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It highly depends on logic of your application, but in the simplest case you can save it inside additional table of the following structure:

```
room_id INT
period_from DATE
period_to DATE
open_from INT
open_to INT
```

You can select open time for a room on particular day using:

```
SELECT open_from, open_to 
FROM intervals
WHERE room_id = 4 AND period_from > '2015-08-19' AND period_to < '2015-08-19'
```

**NOTE** When you add new period, you should validate, that time periods don't intersect for a given room.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It put me on the right path I think. I was thinking about something like this...

https://gyazo.com/6cc52078e5d11a3dbfe0312048b10dff

Comment: Yes, your approach is fine too. It allows to have some predefined periods for all rooms.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I would up-vote it but I'm new and not allowed until I get 15 points.

Comment: That's okey. If you think answer solved your problem you can mark it as [accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).